# In the byte code level, what is the process to initialize an java inner class?

Tags: java, jvm, instrumentation, java-bytecode-asm, javaagents

I wrote a java agent to instrument an open-source benchmark `commons-net`. But I got the following errors:

```java
java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/apache/commons/net/util/SubnetUtils$SubnetInfo.<init>(Lorg/apache/commons/net/util/SubnetUtils;)V @9: invokestatic
  Reason:
    Type uninitializedThis (current frame, stack[2]) is not assignable to 'java/lang/Object'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @9
    flags: { flagThisUninit }
    locals: { uninitializedThis, 'org/apache/commons/net/util/SubnetUtils' }
    stack: { 'org/apache/commons/net/util/SubnetUtils', uninitializedThis, uninitializedThis }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 12ca b800 cf2a 2b5f 59b8 00d3 5fb5 0002
    0x0000010: 2ab7 0003 b800 d6b1                    

    at...
```

and

```java
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/apache/commons/net/tftp/TFTPServer$TFTPTransfer.<init>(Lorg/apache/commons/net/tftp/TFTPServer;Lorg/apache/commons/net/tftp/TFTPPacket;)V @10: invokestatic
  Reason:
    Type uninitializedThis (current frame, stack[2]) is not assignable to 'java/lang/Object'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @10
    flags: { flagThisUninit }
    locals: { uninitializedThis, 'org/apache/commons/net/tftp/TFTPServer', 'org/apache/commons/net/tftp/TFTPPacket' }
    stack: { 'org/apache/commons/net/tftp/TFTPServer', uninitializedThis, uninitializedThis }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 1301 84b8 0189 2a2b 5f59 b801 8d5f b500
    0x0000010: 012a b700 022a 035f 59b8 018d 5fb5 0003
    0x0000020: 2a01 5f59 b801 8d5f b500 042a 2c5f 59b8
    0x0000030: 018d 5fb5 0005 b801 90b1   

    at...
```

What is interesting is that these two errors are both thrown in an inner class and the stack frames are very similar. I guess it just happens when the inner class is being initialized because I see `uninitializedThis` in the stack.

My MethodVisitor adapter is very long and complicated so I did not post it here. I use it to tracing the event of `method_start`, `method_end`, `new_object`, `object_modify`, `PUTFIELD`, `PUTSTATIC`, etc. I need to record the modified object and new object by calling `INVOKESTATIC` to one of my methods. I comment the inserted instruction `DUP` and `INVOKESTATIC` after the `NEW`, but it still report the same error. I think if I can know how the inner class is initialized, debugging would be much easier.

The source code of those two `<init>` method:

```java
public class SubnetUtils {
    ...
    public final class SubnetInfo {
        /* Mask to convert unsigned int to a long (i.e. keep 32 bits) */
        private static final long UNSIGNED_INT_MASK = 0x0FFFFFFFFL;

        private SubnetInfo() {}
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

```java
public class TFTPServer implements Runnable
{
    ...
    private class TFTPTransfer implements Runnable
    {
        private final TFTPPacket tftpPacket_;

        private boolean shutdownTransfer = false;

        TFTP transferTftp_ = null;

        public TFTPTransfer(TFTPPacket tftpPacket)
        {
            tftpPacket_ = tftpPacket;
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

---

I have located the buggy code in my MethodVisitor Adapter class. I mean, when I comment those code, it seems the error is gone. But I still have no idea why this error happened. The `SubnetInfo`'s constructor seems to have no operation to modify any field. I guess maybe it is because of some hidden features for inner class initialization?

```java
    public void visitFieldInsn(int opc, String owner, String name, String desc){
        // Access Static Fields
        if ((opc == GETSTATIC || opc == PUTSTATIC) && shouldIncludeClass(owner)){
            mv.visitLdcInsn(owner);
            mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKESTATIC, MyClass, MyMethod,
                    "(Ljava/lang/String;)V", false);
        }

        if (...){
            if (opc == PUTFIELD){
                Type t = Type.getType(desc);
                if (t.getSize() == 2){
                    mv.visitInsn(DUP2_X1);
                    mv.visitInsn(POP2);
                }else {
                    mv.visitInsn(SWAP);
                }
                mv.visitInsn(DUP);
                mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKESTATIC, MyClass,
                        MyClass.TRACE_OBJ_MODIFY, "(Ljava/lang/Object;)V", false);
                if (t.getSize() == 2){
                    mv.visitInsn(DUP_X2);
                    mv.visitInsn(POP);
                }else {
                    mv.visitInsn(SWAP);
                }
            }else if (opc == PUTSTATIC){
                mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKESTATIC, MyClass,
                        MyClass.TRACE_PUTSTATIC, "()V", false);
            }
        }
        mv.visitFieldInsn(opc, owner, name, desc);
    }
```

---

I have traced only one `PUTFIELD` instruction in `SubnetInfo`'s constructor. In my log:

```
Transform: org/apache/commons/net/util/SubnetUtils$SubnetInfo
**** PUTFIELD found ****
**** className org/apache/commons/net/util/SubnetUtils$SubnetInfo ****
**** methodName <init> ****
**** opc PUTFIELD ****
**** owner org/apache/commons/net/util/SubnetUtils$SubnetInfo ****
**** name this$0 ****
**** desc Lorg/apache/commons/net/util/SubnetUtils; ****
```

What does this `PUTFIELD` instruction mean? Putting the object of the outer class to the field `this$0` of the inner class? Is there any approach to identify the initialization of the inner class?

Comment: You can't use an object before it's constructor is called in any way, shape or form.

Comment: I think I did not do that. BTW, I found the problem is caused by my instrumentation around `PUTFIELD`, but I have no idea why it throws error since the SubnetInfo's constructor seems to have no operation to modify any field. I guess maybe it is because of some hidden features for inner class initialization?

Comment: *"SubnetInfo's constructor seems to have no operation to modify any field"* - It does. Look at the bytecode.

Comment: There is no special process to initialize an inner class. `putfield` instructions are allowed to appear before the invocation of the super constructor, a place where you are not allowed to pass the uninitialized this reference to a static method. The likelihood of encountering such `putfield` instructions is higher for inner classes because they initialize their field holding the outer this reference before invoking the super constructor. But byte code instrumentation code should be prepared for this possibility *in general*.

Answer (score -1):

inner class will call init function of this firstly.It's different from common class constructor.you must assign this to var after init operation.

```
 public org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile(javax.servlet.http.Part, java.lang.String);
flags: ACC_PUBLIC
Code:
  stack=2, locals=3, args_size=3
     0: aload_0
     1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
     4: aload_0
```